# drupal 7 Targeting specific arrays in a page.tpl.php

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

I have a situation where i need two different conditions to be met in order for the title of a  given node to be printed to the page (this bit below is from my page.tpl):

```
<?php if 
($title && ($user->uid == 1) || $title && ($page['#object']['type']['blog_post'])
/* is the node a full blog post? */
): ?>
```

I want to display the title of a node only if the user is logged in. which is working, but i am not sure how to display the title for my specific node type. Obviously I am drilling down into the wrong part of the array. But I can't seem to figure out which part of the array will deliver to satisfy my condition.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $node variable in your page.tpl.php when diaplayed page is node. Node type stores in $node->type. But only for node pages. Node page of type 'blog_post' displays full blog post.

```
<?php if(isset($node) && $node->type == 'blog_post');?>
  <?php print $title; ?>
<?php endif?>
```

In page.tpl will print title only on full nodes of your type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use node.tpl.php for handling specific node parameters,
which you'll find node.tpl.php in /modules/node/node.tpl.php

The node template offers you parameters for checking the view mode ($view_mode) and $title for that node.

P.S., if you want to check if your user is logged in, drupal offers you a function user_is_logged_in()

Comment: thanks @StryKaizer. A couple things, i understand your approach by using the node.tpl is there a way to _without_ using the node.tpl?

Also regarding the user function above one would write something like: `<php? if ($user_is_logged_in): ?> do some stuff... <php? endif;>` 
Thanks for you help